# jQuery Mobile (JQM) previous page

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to implement a swipe-style-navigation "info", as the ones usually appear at the very first start up of an APP, ...you know: a series of info screens you review one after other, with dots and an "exit" button at the bottom of the screen so you can abandon the "info/tutorial" when you want.

My question is about how to implement that exit functionality, as the standard JQM's "Back" button links doesn't take me out of these "info" pages but leads me to the previous info page (as might be expected).

A static link is not an option, as the user can call that "info/tutorial" from multiple pages of the APP.

Also, I can´t use "document.referrer" as it doesn't work as expected.

Finally, I can´t find the way to get access via events, with the help of ui param (ui.prevPage[0].baseURI) as it retrieves "undefined"

Thanks for your time.

Best regards.

P.S.
I'm using JQM 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

1. at the referring page (page-one) link use an "href="page-two.html?referring=page-one"
2. at the referred page (page-two) we use a script like this:

   ```
   function startup(){
        var location=document.URL;
        var exitLink =location.slice(location.lastIndexOf("=")+1,location.length)+".html";
        var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("infoExit");

        for(var i=0,j=elements.length;i<j;i++)
            elements[i].setAttribute("href",exitLink);
   };

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",startup);
   ```

Best regards.